Which tool has been used to make this puzzle?

Bridge, or...?
SE Oban (J)
Part 'un'
Di- Tri- Po-
Dubber
R&L
Pre- v. IC
'P' or TV man
A stat: I=RA
M????: Al, Ga, B (or O), N, ??

Which tool has been used to make this puzzle?

The tool is

 The guillotine. Quite morbid but we'll see why this works in a bit.

Reasoning:

 Let's remove all the punctuation and change the capitalization a bit and give the lines their proper spacing:

 Brid geor
 Seo banj
 Par tun
 Di tripo
 Dub ber
 R L
 Pre vic
 Port v man
 Asta tira
 Mal gaboron

Then,

 By modifying each pair of nonsense words (and adjusting the capitalization again), they become:

 Bridgetown Georgetown
 Seoul Banjul
 Paris Tunis
 Dili Tripoli
 Dublin Berlin
 Rome Lome
 Pretoria Victoria
 Port-Vila Manila
 Astana Tirana
 Male Gaborone

 and all twenty of these are state capitals!

But

 What is this modification anyway? What we did was we added the same nonsense fragment to each nonsense word. Respectively, these fragments are getown, ul, is, li, lin, ome, toria, ila, na, and e. And if we look at the first letters of these fragments, they spell out guillotine!

This is

 appropriate for the puzzle, because we chopped off parts of capitals to form the nonsense words, and it so happens that the guillotine is used for chopping off heads and is a form of capital punishment! (Thanks @psmears for noticing this!)


Oh sorry - I didn't check to see if answered - and well ahead of  mine!

@Tom No worries, and at least you got the j in there first (thanks Weather Vane for noticing!).

Correct, and awarding you the checkmark on basis of time :)

I guess it's a form of rot13(pncvgny chavfuzrag)!

@psmears I'm glad somebody has noticed that! :) I originally debated alluding to that in the title but decided to leave it as an Easter egg in the end...

@psmears Oh of course! I don't know how I missed that...

This sharp puzzle clues a

 guillotine

Each line clues

 two world capital cities like thus

 Bridge, or...? Bridgetown , Georgetown
  SE Oban (J)  -> Seoul, Banjul
 Part 'un'  -> Paris, Tunis
 Di- Tri- Po-  -> Dili, Tripoli
  Dubber -> Dublin, Berlin
  R&L  -> Rome, Lome
  Pre- v. IC  -> Pretoria, Victoria
  'P' or TV man -> Port Vila, Manila
  A stat: I=RA  -> Astana, Tirana
 M????: Al, Ga, B (or O), N, ?? -> Male, Gaborone

 and take the initial letter of each line's added string. An apt tool to chop head places.


Correct :) But I've given oAlt the checkmark for posting an answer slightly sooner. Both good answers with small differences in ways of explaining it...
